# Julia: isposdef() fails for large matrices?

Tags: matrix, julia, sparse-matrix

I have a positive definite covariance matrix `C` of size 3n x 3n constructed from n^2  blocks of size 3x3.

Running `MvNormal` (with e.g a zero mean vector) on this matrix to draw Gaussian random vectors, I am getting the error

```
PosDefException: matrix is not positive definite; Cholesky factorization failed.
```

and indeed checking `isposef(C)` returns `false` when n becomes too large. However my matrix should be positive definite for any n, so it seems that there is some kind of numerical instability (perhaps due to the determinant becoming too small or too large beyond machine precision).

The reproducible code I am using to generate C is below:

```
#######################################################
# inputs
grid_size=10
l_sq = 1 
xmax = 2
#######################################################

# kernel function used to construct covariance matrix C
function corr(x, y, l_sq)
    v=x-y
    d_sq=sum(v.^2)

    n = d_sq/(2l_sq)
    return exp(-n)*(Matrix{Float64}(I, length(x), length(x)))
end 

nb_grid_points = grid_size^3
gaussian_vector_dim = 3*nb_grid_points

oneD_grid = LinRange(-xmax, xmax, grid_size)

# get input set X which indexes grid points
threeD_grid = collect.(Iterators.product(oneD_grid, oneD_grid, oneD_grid))
grid_points = vec(reshape(threeD_grid,:,1))

########################################
# build C by blocks
C = Array{Float64}(undef, gaussian_vector_dim, gaussian_vector_dim)

for i in 1:nb_grid_points
    for j in 1:nb_grid_points
        #block covariance matrix C consist of DxD correlation-function matrices K_i,j for i,j=1,...,nb_grid_points
        C[3*(i-1)+1:(3*i),(3*(j-1)+1):(3*j)] = corr(grid_points[i], grid_points[j],l_sq)
    end
end

#########################################
# plot covariance matrix
plt.imshow(C,cmap="Blues", interpolation="none") 
plt.colorbar() 
plt.title("Covariance matrix")
#########################################
print("C is symmetric:",issymmetric(C))
print("\ndet C=",det(C))
print("\nC is positive definite=",isposdef(C))
```

Maintaining,     `l_sq = 1 , xmax = 2`, the code above gives `isposdef(C) = false` when    `grid_size=10` but  `isposdef(C)=true` if `grid_size` is 9 or less.

Why is this failure occurring and how can I fix it? Perhaps I can help Julia by indicating that the covariance matrix is sparse?

Comment: You can help things along (and save memory) by using a `Symmetric(C)`, since it is symmetric. But even then, this looks like just straight up precision issue (and it actually stems from within dpotrf in LAPACK, which end ups being used here). I managed to trick `cholesky(C*100).U/sqrt(100)` but, trying different scaling factors it's evident that the precision is very poor at the larger indices. So this matrix construction just seems to get poorly condition after a while.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman are there any algorithmic ways around this that you know of? https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01414707v2/document has some ideas on using circulant embedding, but perhabs there is something dumber and easier to try first.

Comment: Finally, you can find out the function in stack trace in which this exception occurs and rewrite it without posdef checking